# Why does this sentence 「雨が降るかもしれないから、傘を持っていったら？」use いったら at the end, is this たら a conditional?

Tags: conditionals

So basically I got this sentence

> 雨が降るかもしれないから、傘を持っていったら？

And my question is, is the たら at the end a conditional? If not what purpose does it serve?